# Path for Alternate CSS URL?

Tags: 2013, powershell, css, path

i am settings the alternate css url using following powershell script, but it did not change the .css file. What path should i use for alternate css? in my case .css file is located at this path:

```
$CssPath = "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES\MyCSS\mycss.css"

    $web = Get-SPWeb http://intranet
    $web.AlternateCssUrl = $CssPath  //what path should i use here? Is it correct path
    $web.AllProperties["__InheritsAlternateCssUrl"] = $True
    $web.Update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly link to the file system file, it would need to be `http://your.spdomain.com/sites/yoursite/_layouts/mycss/mycss.css` or something to that affect.